# Creating custom UIElement classes c#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, shapes, uielement

I'm trying to create custom classes of object which can be drawn on `Canvas`.

For example:

I wish to create a class called `CustomRectangle` which will allow me to create a simple rectangle from given `X` and `Y` location values, along with `Width` and `Height` and will have a `Label` inside it. This `CustomRectangle`. I also wish to register this class to `Mouse Events` such as `MouseMove` in order to move the `Rectangle` on the `Canvas` while clicking and dragging it.

I found several implementations of classes which derive from `UIElement` but those solutions don't allow me register the newly created object to mouse events.

Can such a thing be done? If I wish to create my own private library of "Custom Shapes"?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry forgot to mention it.